# Integrate $\int \frac{x\ln (x)}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}} dx$

Tags: integration

> Integrate $$\int \frac{x\ln (x)}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}} dx$$.

**My Try:**
$$\int \frac{x\ln (x)}{x^3(1-1/x^2)^{3/2}} dx=\int \frac{\frac{1}{x^2}\ln (x)}{(1-\frac{1}{x^2})^{3/2}} dx.$$
Putting $x=\frac{1}{t}$,
I get
$$\int \frac{t^2\ln (\frac{1}{t})}{(1-t^2)^{3/2}(-t^2)} dt=\int \frac{\ln ({t})}{(1-t^2)^{3/2}} dt.$$

After this what to do?

Comment: Start using integration by parts to eliminate the logarithm.

Comment: Dear mathJack  at this step you can use trigonometric substitution $t=\sin{\theta}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One may first integrate by parts,
$$
\int \frac{x\ln (x)}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}} \:dx=-\frac{\ln (x)}{(x^2-1)^{1/2}} +\int \frac1{x(x^2-1)^{1/2}} \:dx
$$ then using the change of variable $u=\dfrac1{(x^2-1)^{1/2}}$, one gets
$$
\int \frac1{x(x^2-1)^{1/2}} \:dx=-\int \frac1{1+u^2} \:du=-\arctan \left(\dfrac1{(x^2-1)^{1/2}}\right),
$$ finally

> $$
> \int \frac{x\ln (x)}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}} \:dx=-\frac{\ln (x)}{(x^2-1)^{1/2}}-\arctan \left(\dfrac1{(x^2-1)^{1/2}}\right)+C.
> $$

Comment: integration by parts is so simple yet so efficient

Answer (score 2):

Check that

$$\int\frac1{t^{3/2}}dx=-2t^{-1/2}+C\implies \int\frac{f'(x)\,dx}{f(x)^{3/2}} =-2f(x)^{-1/2}+C$$

and now just observe that $\;2x=(x^2-1)'\;$ , so by parts:$${}$$

$$\begin{cases}&u=\log x,&u'=\cfrac1x\\{}\\&v'=\cfrac x{(x-1)^{3/2}},&v=-\cfrac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\end{cases}\;\;\implies$$$${}$$

$$\int\frac{x\log x}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}dx=-\frac{\log x}{(x^2-1)^{3/2}}+\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

and remember (or prove...)

$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}=-\arctan\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+C$$

Comment: great to see you back @DonAntonio! We really missed you! <3

Comment: @user153330 Thank you. Nice to see you, too.

Answer (score 2):

Using the substitution $x=\sec(\theta)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{x\log(x)}{\left(x^2-1\right)^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int\log(x)\,\mathrm{d}\left(x^2-1\right)^{-1/2}\\
&=-\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}\\
&=-\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+\int\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=-\frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}+\sec^{-1}(x)+C
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts taking into account that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right]=\frac{1}{(1-t^2)^{3/2}}.
$$
You will get
$$
\int\ln td\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\frac{t\ln t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}-\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt=\frac{t\ln t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}-\arcsin t.
$$